# pagerank code error with the euclidean distance and iterations

Tags: c

I am currently working the following pagerank algorithm:

where `mxm` contains the following:

> 0   50  30  10 
>   0   0   0   0 
>   10  0   0   20
>   0   20  10  30

Here is the code:

```
#define n 4

int mxm[n][n];
int Oj[n];

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
 Oj[i]=0;

 for(j=0; j<n; j++)
 {
  Oj[i]+=mxm[i][j];
 }
}

int Iij[n][n+1];
int k;

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
 Iij[i][0]=0;
 k=1;

 for(j=0; j<n; j++)
 {
  if(mxm[j][i]!=0)
  {
   Iij[i][0]++;
   Iij[i][k]=j;
   k++;
  }
 }
}

double host_rank[n];

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
 host_rank[i]=1;
}

double eucl;
double p,q,lol;

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
 int t=1;
 int sumhost=Iij[i][0];
 double sumPR=0;
 int iteration=0;

 while(t<=sumhost)
 {
  j=Iij[i][t];
  printf("%d \n",t);
  t++;
  sumPR+=(host_rank[j]*mxm[i][j])/Oj[i];
  lol=0;
  eucl=0;

  do
  {
   for(k=0; k<n; k++)
   {
    p=host_rank[k];
    host_rank[i]=((1-d)/n) + (d*sumPR);
    q=host_rank[k];
    lol+=(p-q)*(p-q);
   }
   eucl = (double)sqrt(lol);
  }
  while(eucl<0.01);
 }
}
```

it should perform the following iterations:

Iteration 0:

> h0 1.000
>   h1 1.000
>   h2 1.000
>   h3 1.000

Iteration 1:

> h0 0.321
>   h1 0.793
>   h2 0.463
>   h3 1.124

Iteration 2:

> h0 0.169
>   h1 0.507
>   h2 0.288
>   h3 0.807

Iteration 3:

> h0 0.119
>   h1 0.346
>   h2 0.200
>   h3 0.560

.
.
.

Iteration 9:

> h0 0.062
>   h1 0.119
>   h2 0.081
>   h3 0.170

however, it does not work. (The above is a part, of the full code.)

Can anybody please solve this problem?

It is based on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpht7.png) function.

Comment: `i  Iij[][] host_rank[]  mxm[][] Oj[] k host_rank[]` not defined in this post.

Comment: ... whereas `iteration` is defined but unused.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this section of the code

```
lol=0;
eucl=0;
do{
    for(k=0; k<n; k++){
        p=host_rank[k];
        host_rank[i]=((1-d)/n) + (d*sumPR);
        q=host_rank[k];
        lol+=(p-q)*(p-q);
    }
    eucl = (double)sqrt(lol);
}while(eucl<0.01);
```

Variables `p` and `q` are set to the same value `host_rank[k]`. So unless `i == k` (thus changing the array element between `p` and `q` being read), `lol` will not move from `0`, so `eucl` will be `0`, and the loop will be infinite.

I also suspect that `lol = 0` should be within the `do-while` loop. And unless the variables `i`, `d` , `n` and `sumPR` are shared and altered by another process, the loop, if it repeats, will always repeat.

Comment: i changed the values as you said but the iteration is not done correctly still:
     do{

      for(k=0; k<n; k++){
       if(k==i){
         p=host_rank[k];
         host_rank[i]=((1-d)/n) + (d*sumPR);
            q=host_rank[k];
            lol+=(p-q)*(p-q);
       }
      }
         eucl = (double)sqrt(lol);
     }while(eucl<0.01);

but 
h0: 0.321 
h1:-nan 
h2:0.695 
h3:0.194

Comment: I didn't say what to change, I only said it is probably wrong. I am sorry but I have no idea what the object is. You have added (in the comment) `if(k==i)` but that is not at all what I meant. I meant *unless `i` **happens** to be equal to `k` the loop will not work.*

Comment: ok thanks for the help! it's just a complicated algorithm i was assigned to do.